# How to write a CSV file without using external libraries

Tags: c#

I have already checked out these libraries `oledb`, `Microsoft Text Writer`, and `TextFieldParser`. We are not allowed to use oledb and Microsoft Text Driver on the server. Also, not allowed to use external libraries. I see that TextFieldParser only reads the file. Is there a way to write a CSV file natively in C#? I am aware that write a CSV is pretty complex so I don't want to roll my own solution.

Comment: Focus your effort on rescinding the ridiculous “not allowed to use external libraries” requirement.

Comment: Can someone elaborate on how complex is it to write a csv file? In one of our modules we just concatenate values using commas and dump it in a file, because it's fast

Comment: It can be fairly complex to handle all the edge cases.  Are you putting double quotes around any value that can contain a comma (or your field delimiter)?  How do you handle it if your field can (or can not) contain a field delimiter, but may start and end with a quotation marker?  How do you differentiate them?  How do you handle control characters like \r\n inside a field?  How do you handle headers?

Comment: Of course, *if* you can restrict all the data to be written can not contain the quotation markers, the field separators, and/or row separators, then it becomes much easier to write a valid CSV file.

Comment: Use StreamWriter : writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", string[] myArray));

Comment: @RobertMcKee Seems like OP should've mentioned his CSV file end goal

Comment: I think we'd need to understand your requirements - Are commas present or possible?  What's your existing dataset?  Is there anything that would need to consume that data afterwards?  As noted by others, CSVs aren't complex and a lot of inherent .net capability is already present - not to mention all of the great external libraries the requirements negate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a leadership problem not a programming problem.

Comment: @gravity yes, file has commas and special characters across multiple fields. These files will be on highly protected computers so convincing higher ups is non-negotiable. Not even MS Office is installed on them. I wish they could budge a little.

Comment: @Javed my end goal is to read data from an oracle database. Then write that data to hard disk as csv. Then save the same data to another database table.

Comment: @Luke101 when our Oracle database reading our csv files, which are being generated by  another module, it uses python preprocessor (which is run by the oracle itself) to prepare csv file (well, actually now it's using preprocessor written in Go) which has csv reader/writer built-in. I don't actually know whether Oracle can use post processors when offloading data, but you might do some researches in that matter. What about another databse table - isn't it easier to do with the oracle itself? If not - consider using preprocessors, came in handy for us.

Comment: What is being asked here?  "Does .NET (Framework|Core) provide a CSV writer implementation?"  "What technical details will I need to consider when writing my own CSV writer?"  Or if the question truly is "Is there a way to write a CSV file natively in C#?" then yes, of course, the same way those external CSV libraries do.  If you're having an issue with that implementation you should describe it, but then you also say you _don't_ want to implement it yourself, so I don't know what you want anyone here to do for you.

Answer (score 3):

There are many different implementations of Csv, but the following should create a csv file correctly formatted according to [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180):

```
public string ToCsv(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> input)
{
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach(var line in input)
  {
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",",line.Select(f=>SafeQuote(f))));
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}

public string SafeQuote(string field)
{
  return MustQuote(field)
    ? @"""" + field.Replace(@"""",@"""""") + @""""
    : field;
}

public static bool MustQuote(string field) => 
  field.Any(c=>c == ',' || c == '"' || c == 13 || c == 10);
```